# C++ - Image processing library or a computer vision one?

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision, libraries

I'm interested in performing *feature extraction* using C++ for medical images (i.e; malignant and benign nodules).

What is suitable for me, an *Image processing* library or a *computer vision* one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do feature extraction you should look more into computer vision libraries.  Image processing is more in the of the kind of algorithms Photoshop does, i.e. to enhance/improve/transform images, not the retrieval of information out of them.  The terms are sometimes uses synonymously though.

You might want to check out [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), they provide some feature extractors and it's an easy to use library for C++.

Comment: First: Good answer by Torsten! but just to eliminate some confusion that may exist: Computer Vision actually is a part of Image Processing. Image Processing is quite general and means everthing that takes images, restores, transforms or enhance them or extract information out of these images (i.e. segment objects or calculate/detect edges). Computer vision basically takes that further into detecting and handling the images (tracking). So basically Computer Vision algorithms use techniques from Image Processing... but this is just secondary, the answer and reference to OpenCV is good as it is!

Answer (score 2):

For medical images, I strongly recommend [ITK](http://www.itk.org/), which has been developed specifically for this purpose and is supported by major US government research funding agencies, such as the National Science Foundation, or the National Cancer Institute.

Answer (score 1):

I used [LTIlib](http://ltilib.sourceforge.net/doc/homepage/index.shtml) for crop image processing.
I know medicine is quite a little different, but the complexity of "understanding" aerial images is not trivial, trust me.

I will advocate LTIlib anyway for its "C++" flavour that fits very well. Performance is also pretty good. My (now) old 8 MPix images earned results with LTI in a comparablespeed with MVTec Halcon did.

Answer (score 1):

In image processing you learn to enhance,increase contrast ,sharpness ,find specific shape in images, much like all the photo editor do.
Feature extraction,stereo vision,object tracking  is a part of Computer vision library .If you are working on medical images you will need both images processing toolbox and Computer vision toolbox .For this you can go with openCV .But a better option is to go with MATLAB toolbox which is easy to use.You will probabily need machine learning toolbox later in your research work ,for this matlab will provide a more complete solution.

Comment: "Better" is a subjective term.  MATLAB is surely powerful, but it's expensive and not many people can afford the package.  I'll admit that I use it often, but only a select group of users use it.  I think if you suggested something that was open source / free, people would be more inclined to use it.